# When eliminating the lambda expressions from this grammar, are we missing a production?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I'm working on converting this grammar to CNF (Chomsky Normal Form).

```
S-> abAB
A-> bAB | lambda
B-> BAa | A | lambda
```

So I started off by eliminating the lambda productions, and in doing so I got this:

```
S-> abAB | abB | abA | ab
A-> bAB  | bA  | bB  | b
B-> BAa  | A   | Ba  | Aa  | a
```

I went a little bit further into the conversion process and ran into an issue of adding more unit productions than necessary, so I went and checked the answer key to see what I missed and it turns out that when we remove the lambdas, the following productions are not correct:

```
S-> ab
A-> b
B-> a
```

I would like to know why because it is not obvious to me yet. If we are looking at the production:

```
A-> bAB
```

and A and B can produce lambda, then we are just simply left with b correct? So why is it not a part of our production after eliminating lambda?

After the $\lambda$ eliminination the key has the following grammar:

```
S-> abAB | abA | abB
A-> bAB  | bA  | bB
B-> BAa  | A   | Ba  | Aa
```

Comment: Is "lambda" the empty string in your notation? If so, then something has gone wrong in your first transformation, because A and B can be empty in the first grammar but not in the second.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes "lambda" is the empty string, I just wasn't sure how to insert the symbol.

Comment: The MSE help system when you are composing a question should give you some tips on how to format mathematical symbols like $\lambda$. As for your problem, compare what you have done with the process described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form

Comment: They look fine to me. Does the key give a complete list of the productions that are supposed to remain after $\lambda$-elimination?

Comment: I included the productions after the $\lambda$ elimination in the key. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Talen: I agree with your results, not those of the key.